# How to upgrade from R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On" to R 3.5 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, ubuntu-18.04

I try to install R'mrmlm" in R

When I try:
install.package("‘mrMLM")

I see:
Installing package into ‘/home/ramen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘‘mrMLM’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)

So how to upgrade to R =>3.5?

Comment: Update && upgrade via `apt` for `r-base`?! If you want to install afresh, you take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04).